# AWS SDK stopped working after composer update

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, composer-php

After I run `composer update` on AWS PHP SDK I started to get this error:

```
Fatal error: Interface 'Guzzle\Common\HasDispatcherInterface' not found in <path>
```

There is `HasDispatcherInterface.php` file in `<path>`, but I still get the error. Is this a bug? If it is, is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out this is about a 12 year old bug of PHP. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=18556

When you use `setlocale('tr_TR')`, PHP can not find any class or method has an 'I' letter in its name. Even if its a standart library. Great.